# How to cancel Visual Studio build using command line?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

When I run a build, sometimes I see a code change I forgot. So I want to cancel the build. Due to the build locking up my IDE, I have to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd>, however, it does not respond fast enough.

I am looking for a command line approach so I can just hit a batch file in my quick launch.
I tried this command:

```
Taskkill /IM aspnet_compiler.exe /F
```

However, this only stops the current project from building and the next one in my multi-project solution starts up.

How can i cancel a build using command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come up with a crude method which is working well for me.

I have the following batch script.

```
@echo off
echo KILL BILLd
for /L %%i in (1,1,10) do (
   Taskkill /IM aspnet_compiler.exe /F
   timeout 1
)
```

(Above, 10 = seconds)

I then make a shortcut of that batch script in the same folder which allows me to do the additional.

- Assign an icon image for my quick launch bar.
- Set it to execute minimized.
- Assign a global short cut key combo.

In VS2010, I have set up <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> as my build all. (not rebuild).

For the shortcut and since my fingers usually are still hoving in the area when I see a forgotten code change. My batch shortcut key combo is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.

Answer (score 25):

I had to add the `/t` flag in order to kill the entire `MSBuild.exe` process tree.  That is:

```
taskkill /im msbuild.exe /f /t
```

In my case, I start `MSBuild.exe` from Gnu Emacs and for some reason Gnu Emacs isn't always able to kill the `MSBuild.exe` if I want to restart it.  I use this as a backup.  I'm doing c++ in VS2010.

Comment: What does the `/t` flag do? We need understanding, not just a recipe for the answer.

Comment: /T tells Windows to terminate the process as well as any child processes.  I notice that MSBuild.exe can spawn child processes while running.  Without killing all the children, the compilation may be left in an unpredictable state (or may continue running in some fashion).  A good way to observe is to use the sysinternals tool, Process Explorer (procexp.exe).  You can see MSBuild.exe spawn several children.

Answer (score 7):

The following stops the builds for all projects, across all instances of Visual Studio:

```
taskkill /im msbuild.exe /f
```

Comment: This command does not work. When my visual studio builds, there is no MSBuild.exe in the processes list.

Comment: Visual Studio does not spawn `MSBuild.exe` as a seperate process. It uses the MSBuild "Framework" in process. It doesn't even launch `CSC.EXE` (the C# compiler), btw, it uses an in-process for that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Visual Studio is the compiler.  aspnet_compiler is for compiling views, so that's why you see it spawn in the list.

You can verify by getting [process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) and looking at the process tree.  You'll note devenv never spawns msbuild, csc, or any other compiler.  But devenv does spike in CPU and I/O.

Answer (score 1):

I have this bash script, with flare.

````html
@echo off

REM by jnh from http://www.chris.com/ascii/index.php?art=objects/explosives
echo "     _.---------------  "
echo " _--                  --_  "
echo "-                        -)   "
echo "|                         |   "
echo " \._                   _./  "
echo "    ```--. . , . .--'''   "
echo "          | |   |    "
echo "       .-=||  | |=-.    "
echo "        `-=#$$$$$#=-'   "
echo "          | ;  :|    "
echo "  _____.,-#$$$$$#&#~,._____   "
 
echo NUKE IT ALLLLLLL

REM kills all MSBuild processes
taskkill /F /IM MSBuild.exe /T

REM Just holds command window open long enough to admire explosion.
timeout 1
````

Answer (score 0):

Actually we can also use the GUI of **Resource Monitor** to do it.
[image]

For example, when we compile a project, some files are occupied, such as "Unable to copy" bla bla.

**Steps:**

**Task manager** ->

**Performance** ->

**Resource Monitor** ->

**Associated Handler** ->

**search** "file name which is occupied."

The strength of this method is intuitive and no need to remember DOS commands, but the drawback of this is we need to search and operate several times.

Answer (score -1):

Go to the menu BUILD and then click in the option: CANCEL. tested in VS2013.